# Creating a Managed Package to Submit to the AppExchange

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, package

Created a package that we want to submit for approval for listing on the AppExchange. 
I have a developer who created a developer edition and tried to create the managed package we got an error that said the developer edition was not connected to a partner account. 
So then we created a developer sandbox built off of our production org thinking that because our production org must be connected to the partner account. But we don't seem to have create managed packages permissions at all in that developer org. And when we try to create a new managed package, the page gives link to developer.salesforce.com to create a developer org.

Which we did at first and that doesn't work. What am I missing? How do we create a managed package in a developer org that we can use to submit for approval to the AppExchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you submit your app to app exchange you need to be a salesforce ISV partner. you can signup for that program using following link

[Salesforce Partner signup](https://partnersignup.salesforce.com/)

once your signup approved from salesforce you will see following menu option under publishing tab at [Partner dashboard](https://partners.salesforce.com) from where you can connect your developer org with your publishing ISV account.

[image]

Note: Your ISV account will be different from the ISV account.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the complete steps for app exchange publish

So here are the steps. I numbered each step because the order is fairly important - in most cases, you cannot move forward without completing the previous step.

1) **Create a Dev Org**

This is the org you use to develop your app and create the initial app packages. If you haven't done this already, you can get free developer editions here. I normally have several dev orgs, and use them for development, testing and packaging. Don't wait until you are done developing to continue the process - when your app is close to being done, you should start thinking about the next steps.

2) **Become a Salesforce.com Partner**

The Salesforce Partner Portal allows you, as SFDC states, to [join the Salesforce.com Partner Ecosystem](https://partnersignup.salesforce.com/). You can register to the Partner portal here. This is a very important step because virtually all future steps start in the Partner Portal, or from an org that was created using the Partner Portal.

3) **Create Test Orgs**

One of the benefits of being a Salesforce Partner is that you can create lots of test orgs that you can use to test the packages you created in the Dev Orgs from step 1 with different licenses and configuration options. This is a very important step, especially if you want Group and Professional users to use your app. From the Partner Portal, you can request orgs that include the following licenses: Enterprise, Platform, One-App, Professional, Group, and Non-Profit. To get a Test Org, you need to login to the Partner Portal (from step 2), click on the "Create a Test Org" button or link, select the edition you want to test with in the dropdown, and submit.

4) **Create a Partner Dev Org**

Partner Dev Orgs are beefier versions of regular dev orgs. You will use this org to store and package your production code (Managed - Released), and later create upgrades and push patches. Although you can use a regular org for this step, I prefer the bigger org that is available to you as a partner. To get a Partner Dev Org, you need to login to the Partner Portal (from step 2), click on the "Create a Test Org" button or link, select the "Partner Developer Edition" option in the Edition dropdown, and submit. Once you create your final managed released package, be sure to go test it again in the Test Orgs you created in step 3.

5) **Create an AppExchange Provider Profile**

By now you should have a Managed - Released package in your Partner Dev Org (step 4). You don't need to have your ready-for-primetime package yet, but you should be pretty close. Creating an AppExchange provider profile will allow you to list and publish your AppExchange App. To create your AppExchange profile, log into your Partner Dev Org and click on the link provided on the detail page of your latest package; then click on the Start Publishing button to create your AppExchange provider profile. When creating your profile, it is very important that you link the profile to the Partner Portal user you created in step 2. The user name and password for the AppExchange provider profile will be the same as your Partner Dev Org credentials from step 4.

6) **Create an AppExchange App Listing**

Once you have an AppExchange Provider Profile, you can go to the Publishing tab, where you can create a new listing. A new listing is always private until the app passes the security review. While private, your app has a link on the AppExchange (which you can send to potential users), but it is not listed publicly and does not show up in searches. In this step you need your marketing and messaging content to be ready - some of the fields are very specific (like max length of certain text, and exact image size for logos), so you will probably need to edit your private listing a few time before it is ready to be published.

7) **Submit Your App for Review**

To go live on the AppExchange (make your listing public), your app needs to pass a security review by Salesforce. To start that process, you need to go to your private listing and click on the Offering tab. In the "Your Uploaded Packages" section, select the latest version of your app in the dropdown and click the "Start Review" link in the packages table. Only Managed-Released packages show up in the dropdown, so make sure you already created one before you go through this step. Once you start the review process, a case is automatically added to the Partner Portal (step 2) and you will receive an email with further instructions. It takes 6-8 weeks to gather and submit test result, pay the $300 fee, and go through the process. There are lots of moving parts in this step, so I may put together another post just for this step later on so stay tuned.

8) **Create Test Drive Org**

The Test Drive Org, gives your users the ability to sample your app before they install it. If set up, the AppExchange listing includes a Test Drive link that logs the user into a preconfigured developer edition org as a read-only user. If users of your app need edit/create credentials to make the demo useful, you should probably skip this step. To set up a Test Drive, Go to the Offering tab in your app listing (from step 6). In the "Test Drive" section click on the "Create Test Drive" link to get started. You'll need to create appropriate demo data and configure your application once the org is created - note that the admin user name for the new org is user@.demo. When the test drive org is ready, go back to the "Test Drive" section on the Offering tab and add the org using the read-only user credentials (eval@.demo).

9) **Create Lead Management Org**

Salesforce allows you to manage your leads even if you are not an ISVForce partner. However, that means that you'll need to get a Salesforce org (and pay for licenses) to be able to manage the leads from the AppExchange. You can link any standard Salesforce Org (not dev org) that has web-to-lead enabled. In lieu of having the License Management Application that is available to ISVForce partners, you can add custom fields and objects to your org to help you manage licenses. You can link the AppExchange listing to your Salesforce org, go to the Leads tab in your app listing (from step 6), and click on the "Change Organization" link.

That's it. Once your security review process from step 7 is complete, you application will be public on the AppExchange!

Comment: What is the cost to go the Managed App path?

Comment: HI @csmba Salesforce don't take any cost from you for app submission.

Comment: There's security fee of USD 2700 for paid apps; for free apps there's no fees.